diccionario a partir de txt
quiero empezar mi practica
Lo que más me sucede es que quiero un diccionario que contenga los datos las claves vienen dadas por sus DNI, los valores son, a su vez, una instancia de la clase persona conteniendo, dicha instancia,
he hecho esta funcion
def leeEmpleados(f, d):
d={}
voluntarios=[]

archivo=open(f,'r')
linea=archivo.readline()

while (linea!=''):  #Hasta encontrar final de archivo
    datos=linea.split(',')  # datos separados por comas
    DNI=str(datos[0])
    nom=str(datos[1])
    apellidos=str(datos[2])
    movil=int(datos[3])
    CC=str(datos[4])
    d={'dnicedula':DNI,
        'nombre': nom,
        'apell':apellidos,
        'movil':movil,
        'CC':CC}
    print(datos)
    voluntarios.append(d)
            # Lee la siguiente linea
    
    linea=archivo.readline()
    n=len(voluntarios)
    print(' Se recuperaron '+ str(n) + ' registros')

Peno no se como modificarla para que me de el diccionario asi:{'52736428P': <persona.persona object at 0x16cf7d280>, '47416499K': <persona.persona object at 0x17960b3d0>....
Ademas no me almacena nada solo se que lo hace porque al mostrarlo por pantalla lo veo

Si quieres <persona.persona object at 0x16cf7d280>, primero tienes que crear una clase persona.

yo he hecho esto:

class persona:
# Definimos los atributos de la clase
NIF = ''
nombre = ''
apellido= ''
movil = ''
CCC= ''
fecha=''
def init(self, datos):
'''
Constructor de la clase persona. Almacena los datos leídos de un archivo'''self.name = datos[1]
self.apellido = datos[2]
self.movil = datos[3]
self.CCC = datos[4]
self.fecha = datos[5]

Para agregar aclaraciones a tu pregunta, pulsa en [edit]. Como verás, el código es ilegible en los comentarios, además de que son efímeros.

Empecemos de cero:
class Persona:

    def __init__(self, DNI, nombre, apellido, movil, CCC):
        ''' Constructor de la clase persona. Almacena los datos leídos de un archivo'''
        self.DNI = DNI
        self.name = nombre
        self.apellido = apellido
        self.movil = movil
        self.CCC = CCC

    def __str__(self):
        return '\n'.join([f"dni cédula: {self.DNI}", f"nombre: {self.name}", f"apellido: {self.apellido}",
                          f"movil: {self.movil}", f"CCC: {self.CCC}"])

Es costumbre usar mayúscula para los nombres de clase.
El método __init__ ha sido redefinido para explicitar sus parámetros. Es mala práctica usar una lista, pues no muestra ni el tipo ni el número de argumentos a recibir.
También eliminamos los atributos de clase, que no tienen lógica ni sentido en este caso.
Finalmente, definimos el método mágico __str__(), que devuelve la representación textual del objeto en cuestión, lista para imprimir. Este método es llamado automáticamente por Python cuando tiene que imprimir un objeto.
Si no defines este método, Python usara un formato por default del estilo
<__main__.Persona object at 0x7f05ac90e570>
<__main__.Persona object at 0x7f05ac90e660>

que no es muy informativo.
El proceso
Definimos una función que recibe el nombre del archivo y lo procesa, devolviendo la lista de voluntarios.
Usamos el formato with open(f, 'r') as archivo: para abrir y automáticamente cerrar el archivo al terminarse.
Usamos el operador morsa := para 1) leer una línea del archivo y 2) chequear el fin de archivo en while linea := archivo.readline(): Esto simplifica el código.
Con los datos leidos, creamos un objeto del tipo Persona y lo agregamos a la lista:
def obtener_voluntarios(f):
    voluntarios = []

    with open(f, 'r') as archivo:
        while linea := archivo.readline():
            DNI, nombre, apellido, movil, CCC = linea.split(',')
            persona = Persona(DNI, nombre, apellido, movil, CCC)
            print(persona)
            voluntarios.append(persona)
    return voluntarios

El programa principal se reduce a llamar a esta función para obtener la lista y luego imprimir la cuenta:
vol = obtener_voluntarios("datos.csv")
print(f'Se recuperaron {len(vol)} registros')

Demo
Con estos datos
1-9, raul, ugalde, 941435678, 123
2-4, jorge, gomez, 988346754, abc

se produce:
dni cédula: 1-9
nombre:  raul
apellido:  ugalde
movil:  941435678
CCC:  123

dni cédula: 2-4
nombre:  jorge
apellido:  gomez
movil:  988346754
CCC:  abc

Se recuperaron 2 registros

Process finished with exit code 0


entiendo que tengo primero hacer el clase Persona no? cuando lo pongo me dice que no encuentra persona

deben estar en el mismo programa?

esta genial pero porque a mi no me lo registraba asi?
